# NASA C coding rules : misuse of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

This document http://pixelscommander.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/P10.pdf describes the 10 internal rules used by NASA/JPL laboratory to code safely in C. Very interesting.

Rule 9 says that :

> Rule: The use of pointers should be restricted. Specifically, no more than one level of
>   dereferencing is allowed. (...) Function pointers are not permitted.
>   Rationale : Pointers are easily misused, even by experienced programmers. (...)

My questions are :

1. how do you handle a 2 dimensional matrix of elements if only 1 level of derefercing is allowed ?
2. if you write a generic algorithm (numerical integration, zero or minimum finding algorithm, etc), how do you use it if function pointers are not allowed ? Do you have to copy paste the code every time with a different function ?
3. do you understand what "pointers are often misused" could refer to ?

Comment: "Pointers are often misused" probably means "Pointers often lead to code that crashes".

Comment: ...or that runs, with unexpected results because of pointer problems. i.e. returning a memory address when you're expecting a value.

Comment: There's a big difference between "not allowed" and "should be restricted".  Don't ask us, pick up the phone and talk to somebody at JPL so you get facts instead of guesses.

Answer (score 6):

1. Do the indexing by hand. For an mxn matrix, for point i,j, the index is [i+j*n]. Doesn't work for jagged arrays.
2. Yes, or use macro madness.
3. Violating strict aliasing, accessing uninitialized data, accessing freed data, accessing out of bounds data, incorrect casting of what the pointer points to, incorrect casting of the pointer as an integer, casting a function pointer to a `void*`, proliferating `void*` unnecessarily throughout the code, not freeing data, double freeing data, freeing stack allocated data...

Comment: Let me add that C can handle real multidimensional arrays since C99. You can declare them as stack variables, easily allocate them dynamically using a single `malloc()` call and the correct pointer type, and just as easily pass them to functions. So, you are not thrown back to doing the indexing by hand.

Comment: @cmaster, could you write a small piece of code to illustrate your comment ?

Comment: By using [i+j*n] you are relying on compiler optimization to eliminate the product and sum, but I guess such performance-critical code will use "*ptr++" anyway.

Comment: @user3528438 Exactly. Use [i+j*n] for random access/seeking.

Comment: @Istopopoki No problem. Function taking 3D array (pointer to a 2D array): `void foo(int width, int height, int depth, int (*array)[height][width])`, stack allocation: `int array[depth][height][width];`, dynamic allocation: `int (*array)[height][width] = malloc(depth*sizeof(*array));`, passing any of these to `foo()`: `foo(width, height, depth, array)`, accessing the elements of any of these: `array[z][y][x]`. Satisfied?

Comment: @cmaster I see, thanks. Does that mean in the dynamic allocation example that 'depth' value can be defined at runtime, while 'height' and 'width' must be static ?

Comment: @Istopopoki Note the way that `foo()` takes the sizes of the array as parameters: All these sizes may be runtime sizes since C99. All which C requires is that the sizes must be declared before the array pointer in the parameter list of `foo()`. You can't do that in C++, however, C++ forbids runtime sizes of array types. In that respect C is much more powerful than C++.

Answer (score 6):

> how do you handle a 2 dimensional matrix of elements if only 1 level of derefercing is allowed ?

```
void foo( int (*matrix)[COLS], size_t rows ) // one level of dereference
{
  ...
  matrix[i][j] = new_value();
}

int main( void )
{
  int m[ROWS][COLS];
  ...
  foo( m, ROWS );
}
```

> if you write a generic algorithm (numerical integration, zero or minimum finding algorithm, etc), how do you use it if function pointers are not allowed ? Do you have to copy paste the code every time with a different function ?

NASA *isn't* using C for numerical work like that; there are *far* better tools available.  But yes, you'd have to write non-generic code.

> do you understand what "pointers are often misused" could refer to ?

One example of pointer misuse would be *type punning*; using a pointer to force a bit pattern to be interpreted as a different type:

```
double pi = 3.14159;
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *) &pi;
for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof pi; i++ )
  printf( "%02x\n", bytes[i] );
```

The danger is if you decide to change the value stored in `pi` by altering one of the values in `bytes`:

```
bytes[1] = 0x00;
```

While useful in some cases, this kind of programming *destroys* the ability to validate code.  Any tool that's looking for changes to `pi` would most likely miss this.

NASA is most likely using C for low-level system controllers, avionics, and similar systems where complicated data structures and algorithms really aren't necessary, but where predictability and robust error handling are *critical*.  Pointer operations open way too many "back doors" that can't easily be found and validated.

You kind of elided the important parts of that rationale:

> Rationale: Pointers are easily misused, even by experienced programmers. They can
>   **make it hard to follow or analyze the flow of data in a program, especially by toolbased
>   static analyzers**. Function pointers, similarly, can **seriously restrict the types of
>   checks that can be performed by static analyzers** and should only be used if there is a
>   strong justification for their use, and ideally alternate means are provided to assist
>   tool-based checkers determine flow of control and function call hierarchies. For
>   instance, **if function pointers are used, it can become impossible for a tool to prove
>   absence of recursion**, so alternate guarantees would have to be provided to make up
>   for this loss in analytical capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

1. How do you handle a 2 dimensional matrix of elements if only 1 level of derefercing is allowed ?

Answer: by declaring fixed array lengths so you don't need more than one level of indirection.

```
void blaster(char array [5][50]) {}
```

2. If you write a generic algorithm (numerical integration, zero or minimum finding algorithm, etc), how do you use it if function pointers are not allowed ? Do you have to copy paste the code every time with a different function ?

Answer: by using identifiers and `case` statements.

```
switch (rocketfunction) {
    case LAND:      reversethrust(); break;
    case TAKEOFF:   fullthrust(); break;
    default:        convert_Feet_2_Metres(height);
}
```

3. Do you understand what "pointers are often misused" could refer to ?

Answer: just look at the plethora of StackOverflow questions relating to pointer misuse.

Comment: Aren't switch statements converted to static function tables? Is the point to hide the use of function pointers, or to leave it to the compiler, or to prevent it altogether? Thanks!